# Insert JSONL with two columns of comma separated fields into separate rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, database-design, insert, json

I have json datas in the format as shown below.

**the number of objects under 'images'(VIEWS, ROOMS, etc.) varied for each JSON object. Not all objects have VIEWS...POOL, it may only have ROOMS.

```
    "propertyId":{"ea":"12345678","h":"","vo":""},
    "thumbnail":{"width":1000,"height":500,"link":"xxx.jpg"},
    "hero":{"title":"Featured Image","width":1000,"height":669,"link":"yyy.jpg"},
    "images":{
       "VIEWS":[
        {"title":"View from Property","width":1000,"height":666,"link":"a1.jpg"},
        {"title":"View from Property","width":1000,"height":666,"link":"a2.jpg"}
       ],
        "ROOMS":[
            {"title":"Room","width":1000,"height":669,"link":"b1.jpg"},
            {"title":"Room","width":1000,"height":662,"link":"b2.jpg"}
       ],
        "EXTERIOR":[
            {"title":"Terrace","width":1000,"height":666,"link":"c1.jpg"},
            {"title":"Terrace","width":1000,"height":666,"link":"c2.jpg"}
       ],
        "AMENITIES":[
             {"title":"Property Amenity","width":1000,"height":666,"link":"d1.jpg"}
       ],
        "POOL":[
            {"title":"Outdoor Pool","width":1000,"height":666,"link":"e1"},
            {"title":"Outdoor Pool","width":1000,"height":666,"link":"e2.jpg"}
    ]}
    }
```

I wanted to insert the following data into the table with the following format in MySQL Ver 8.0.23 database.
[image]

JSON -> Table Reference

```
    HotelId = propertyId.ea
    hero_url = hero.link
    hero_title = hero.title
    media_title = images.(VIEWS/ROOMS/EXTERIOR/...).title 
    media_url = images.(VIEWS/ROOMS/EXTERIOR/...).link
    >> ...other objects may have different category (VIEWS/ROOMS...)
    created_at and updated_at = date
```

After searching through the old topics, I was able to use the select statement below to display the format above. However, I'm confused as to it how works when using `INSERT`.

```
  SELECT t.HotelID, t.hero_url, t.hero_title,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.media_title, ',', n.n), ',', -1) media_title, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.images, ',', n.n), ',', -1) images
  FROM hotel_sample.property_photos t CROSS JOIN 
  (
   SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n
     FROM 
    (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
   ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
    ORDER BY n 
   ) n
 WHERE n.n <= 1 + (LENGTH(t.media_title) - LENGTH(REPLACE(t.media_title, ',', '')))
 ORDER BY HotelID
```

Would appreciate if anyone could show me how I could insert the above JSON data into the table. (MySQL Ver 8.0.23)

```
CREATE TABLE `property_photos` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `HotelID` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hero_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hero_title` text,
  `category` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `media_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `media_title` text,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

Comment: What is "JSONL" in the title?

Comment: Don't use JSON when you need a traditional relational schema.  Split the lists _before_ inserting in the table(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parsing consists from 2 stages/queries.

First stage parses root object properties.

```sql
WITH
cte1 AS (SELECT @json AS val)
SELECT val->>"$.propertyId.ea" + 0 AS ea,
       val->>"$.propertyId.h" AS h,
       val->>"$.propertyId.vo" AS vo,
       val->>"$.thumbnail.width" + 0 AS t_width,
       val->>"$.thumbnail.height" + 0 AS t_height,
       val->>"$.thumbnail.link" AS t_link,
       val->>"$.hero.title" AS h_title,
       val->>"$.hero.width" + 0 AS h_width,
       val->>"$.hero.height" + 0 AS h_height,
       val->>"$.hero.link" AS h_link
FROM cte1
```

Output:

| ea | h | vo | t_width | t_height | t_link | h_title | h_width | h_height | h_link |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345678 |  |  | 1000 | 500 | xxx.jpg | Featured Image | 1000 | 669 | yyy.jpg |

Second step parses its subobjects.

```sql
WITH
cte1 AS (SELECT @json AS val),
cte2 AS (SELECT val->>"$.propertyId.ea" + 0 AS ea,
                val->"$.images.VIEWS" AS views,
                val->"$.images.ROOMS" AS rooms,
                val->"$.images.EXTERIOR" AS exterior,
                val->"$.images.AMENITIES" AS amenities,
                val->"$.images.POOL" AS pool
         FROM cte1),
cte3 AS (SELECT cte2.ea, 'views' type, jsontable.*
         FROM cte2
         CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(CAST(cte2.views AS JSON),
                               "$[*]" COLUMNS (title VARCHAR(255) PATH "$.title",
                                               width INT PATH "$.width",
                                               height INT PATH "$.height",
                                               link VARCHAR(255) PATH "$.link")) jsontable
         WHERE cte2.views IS NOT NULL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT cte2.ea, 'rooms' type, jsontable.*
         FROM cte2
         CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(CAST(cte2.rooms AS JSON),
                               "$[*]" COLUMNS (title VARCHAR(255) PATH "$.title",
                                               width INT PATH "$.width",
                                               height INT PATH "$.height",
                                               link VARCHAR(255) PATH "$.link")) jsontable
         WHERE cte2.rooms IS NOT NULL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT cte2.ea, 'exterior' type, jsontable.*
         FROM cte2
         CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(CAST(cte2.exterior AS JSON),
                               "$[*]" COLUMNS (title VARCHAR(255) PATH "$.title",
                                               width INT PATH "$.width",
                                               height INT PATH "$.height",
                                               link VARCHAR(255) PATH "$.link")) jsontable
         WHERE cte2.exterior IS NOT NULL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT cte2.ea, 'amenities' type, jsontable.*
         FROM cte2
         CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(CAST(cte2.amenities AS JSON),
                               "$[*]" COLUMNS (title VARCHAR(255) PATH "$.title",
                                               width INT PATH "$.width",
                                               height INT PATH "$.height",
                                               link VARCHAR(255) PATH "$.link")) jsontable
         WHERE cte2.amenities IS NOT NULL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT cte2.ea, 'pool' type, jsontable.*
         FROM cte2
         CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(CAST(cte2.pool AS JSON),
                               "$[*]" COLUMNS (title VARCHAR(255) PATH "$.title",
                                               width INT PATH "$.width",
                                               height INT PATH "$.height",
                                               link VARCHAR(255) PATH "$.link")) jsontable
         WHERE cte2.pool IS NOT NULL)
SELECT * FROM cte3;
```

Output:

| ea | type | title | width | height | link |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345678 | views | View from Property | 1000 | 666 | a1.jpg |
| 12345678 | views | View from Property | 1000 | 666 | a2.jpg |
| 12345678 | rooms | Room | 1000 | 669 | b1.jpg |
| 12345678 | rooms | Room | 1000 | 662 | b2.jpg |
| 12345678 | exterior | Terrace | 1000 | 666 | c1.jpg |
| 12345678 | exterior | Terrace | 1000 | 666 | c2.jpg |
| 12345678 | amenities | Property Amenity | 1000 | 666 | d1.jpg |
| 12345678 | pool | Outdoor Pool | 1000 | 666 | e1.jpg |
| 12345678 | pool | Outdoor Pool | 1000 | 666 | e2.jpg |

---

You may use these queries as a rowsource for INSERT statement, combine these queries if needed.

If `"$.propertyId.ea"` is not enough for unique root object identifying then add necessary columns into the last step query.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=81ebab30922db5f99abd90c8b39622e5

PS. `+ 0` converts extracted string value to numeric datatype.